# validity.rangeUnderflow is not working

Tags: javascript, validation, ecmascript-6

I'm making a little text web application where you can send messages to different contacts.

If you send the message, I want it to be a minimum of 3 characters.

The problem I get now is that if I fill in 1 or 2 characters I won't get the "Too short" Error message. I do something wrong, but I can't really figure out what.

```js
const handeSubmitForm = e => {
      const $form  = e.target;
      if(!$form.checkValidity()){
        e.preventDefault();
        $form.querySelector(`.error`).textContent = `Fill in the correct fields`;
        Array.from($form.elements).forEach(showValidationInfo);
      }
    };

    const handleInputField = e => {
      const $field = e.currentTarget;
      if($field.checkValidity()){
        $field.parentElement.querySelector(`.error`).textContent = ``;
      }
    };

    const showValidationInfo = $field => {
      let message;

      if($field.validity.valueMissing ){
        message = `Required`;
      }

      if($field.validity.rangeUnderflow){
        message = `Too short`;
      }

      if(message){
        $field.parentElement.querySelector(`.error`).textContent = message;
      }
    };

    const handleBlurField = e => {
      const $field = e.currentTarget;
      showValidationInfo($field);
    };

    const addValidationListeners = fields => {
      fields.forEach($field => {
        $field.addEventListener(`blur`, handleBlurField);
        $field.addEventListener(`input`, handleInputField);
      });
    };

  const init = () => {

    const $form = document.querySelector(`.message-form`);
    $form.noValidate = true;
    $form.addEventListener(`submit`, handeSubmitForm );
    addValidationListeners(Array.from($form.elements));

  };
  init();
```

```html
<form class="message-form">
 <span class="error"></span>
  <div class="wrap">
   <span class="error"></span>
   <input type="text" class="message-input" required minlength="3" 
   placeholder="Write your message..." />
  <button type="submit" class="submit"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation `validity.rangeUnderflow` compares the values instead of its length. Use `validation.tooShort`.

```js
const handeSubmitForm = e => {
      const $form  = e.target;
      if(!$form.checkValidity()){
        e.preventDefault();
        $form.querySelector(`.error`).textContent = `Fill in the correct fields`;
        Array.from($form.elements).forEach(showValidationInfo);
      }
    };

    const handleInputField = e => {
      const $field = e.currentTarget;
      if($field.checkValidity()){
        $field.parentElement.querySelector(`.error`).textContent = ``;
      }
    };

    const showValidationInfo = $field => {
      let message;

      if($field.validity.valueMissing ){
        message = `Required`;
      }

      if($field.validity.tooShort){
        message = `Too short`;
      }

      if(message){
        $field.parentElement.querySelector(`.error`).textContent = message;
      }
    };

    const handleBlurField = e => {
      const $field = e.currentTarget;
      showValidationInfo($field);
    };

    const addValidationListeners = fields => {
      fields.forEach($field => {
        $field.addEventListener(`blur`, handleBlurField);
        $field.addEventListener(`input`, handleInputField);
      });
    };

  const init = () => {

    const $form = document.querySelector(`.message-form`);
    $form.noValidate = true;
    $form.addEventListener(`submit`, handeSubmitForm );
    addValidationListeners(Array.from($form.elements));

  };
  init();
```

```html
<form class="message-form">
 <span class="error"></span>
  <div class="wrap">
   <span class="error"></span>
   <input type="text" class="message-input" required minlength="3" 
   placeholder="Write your message..." />
  <button type="submit" class="submit"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```